# 'Sorry, your session has expired', on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, cartflows

I get 'Sorry, your session has expired' on Checkout page. I am using CartFlows for creating a funnel, and Stripe as a payment processor. All other flows and checkout pages are working well except the last one: https://awesometuts.com/ch

It works sometimes, but mostly gives me session expired. In console I have no error related to that. Documentation is no help.

I am using Cyberpanel and my own VPS for a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. Issue was with CloudFlare. I was using some speed optimisations that created some kind of conflict. Have turned them off, now all runs smoothly. Thanks

Comment: what were the optimizations?

Comment: Cloudflares' Rocket Loader

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the service you're using is creating the Checkout sessions too early and providing the URL or redirect after the session has expired.

If you control the Checkout session creation, you need to do that closer to the customer redirect. If the platform you use controls this, you should reach out to them to understand expected behaviour and get some help with fixing this issues.

The maximum (and default) time to expiry is 24 hours after creation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-expires_at